# SignalR .net core Filters

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

Does SignalR have a similar options as the MVC Filters described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0)?

With MVC I can create an Action Filter (derived from IAsyncActionFilter) and use it as an attribute on a MVC method.

For example:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyCustomAsyncActionFilter))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAlbums() { }
```

With the above example, MyCustomAsyncActionFilter can then be implemented to handle custom code that needs to be executed prior to executing the method.

What's the equivalent of the above when working with SignalR methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no feature like ASP.NET SignalR hub pipelines in SignalR Core yet (see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5353)) and the MVC filters don't apply to SignalR.

A workaround might be to implement your own HubDispatcher and override the DispatchMessageAsync method:

```
public class CustomHubDispatcher<THub> : DefaultHubDispatcher<THub> where THub : Hub
{
    public CustomHubDispatcher(
        IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory,
        IHubContext<THub> hubContext,
        IOptions<HubOptions<THub>> hubOptions,
        IOptions<HubOptions> globalHubOptions,
        ILogger<CustomHubDispatcher<THub>> logger) : base(serviceScopeFactory, hubContext, hubOptions, globalHubOptions, logger)
    {
    }

    public override Task DispatchMessageAsync(HubConnectionContext connection, HubMessage hubMessage)
    {
        switch (hubMessage)
        {
            case InvocationMessage invocationMessage:
                {
                    // do something here
                    break;
                }
        }
        return base.DispatchMessageAsync(connection, hubMessage);
    }
}
```

and use it in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSignalR();
services.AddSingleton(typeof(HubDispatcher<>), typeof(CustomHubDispatcher<>));
```

Comment: Thanks, this will have to do for now, have a great day!

Comment: Note: `HubDispather` and `DefaultHubDispatcher` are now `internal` as of v3.
So they can no longer be used in this way. There doesn't seem to be an alternative currently. Apparently there will be a "pipeline" that can be customized, coming in V5

Answer (score 2):

.NET 5 supports [Hub Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hub-filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

From the docs:

```
services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    // Global filters will run first
    options.AddFilter<CustomFilter>();
}).AddHubOptions<ChatHub>(options =>
{
    // Local filters will run second
    options.AddFilter<CustomFilter2>();
});
```

Filters need to implement [IHubFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubfilter?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Hub filters seem to work only for methods but not for messages. Any idea how to deal with messages? See also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66553201/1706507