# Filter Outgoing SignalR Core Hub Messages

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, .net-5, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using SignalR and .Net 5.0 and leveraging [Hub Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hub-filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to execute code on incoming Invokations to my SignalR Hub.

I am looking for a way to do the same thing with outgoing messages from the Hub to the Client but seem to be coming up with no options.
Perhaps alternatively, I would love to hook into and execute code specifically when the built in [Ping Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.protocol.pingmessage?view=aspnetcore-5.0) are sent out.

It looks like similar functionality used to be possible in the old version's HubPipeLineModule but I have not been able to find any way to achieve this in current SignalR. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[HubLifetimeManager](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v6.0.10/src/SignalR/server/Core/src/HubLifetimeManager.cs) is responsible for sending messages to clients and it is possible to inject your custom one, right before registering SignalR:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(HubLifetimeManager<>), typeof(CustomHubLifetimeManager<>));
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
```

where

```
public class CustomHubLifetimeManager<THub> : DefaultHubLifetimeManager<THub> where THub : Hub
{
     public override Task SendAllAsync(string methodName, object?[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        //todo: do your stuff
        return base.SendAllAsync(methodName, args, cancellationToken);
    }
    //todo: override rest of the methods
}
```

It works fine, however this approach looks a bit hacky for me.

Comment: I was researching a slightly different problem however this idea helped me a ton. The ability to register your own hub-lifetime-service came very handy. Just wanted to say thank you!